# Ruby local variable is undefined

Tags: ruby, local-variables

I have the following Ruby code:

```
local_var = "Hello"

def hello
  puts local_var
end

hello
```

I get the following error:

```
local_variables.rb:4:in 'hello': undefined local variable or method 'local_var' 
for main:Object (NameError) from local_variables.rb:7:in '<main>'
```

I always thought that local variables are not accessible from outside of the block, function, closure, etc.

But now I defined local variable in the file and try to get an access from the function  **INSIDE** the same file.

What's wrong with my understanding?

Comment: You said "I always thought that local variables are not accessible from outside of the […] function". So why are you surprised that your local variable is only looking inside the function on the `puts` line?

Comment: because other programming languages differ

Comment: try @local_var = "Hello"

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In Ruby local variables only accessible in the scope that they are defined. Whenever you enter/leave a Class, a Module or a Method definiton your scope changes in Ruby.

For instance :

```
v1 = 1

class MyClass # SCOPE GATE: entering class
  v2 = 2
  local_variables # => ["v2"]

  def my_method # SCOPE GATE: entering def
    v3 = 3
    local_variables  # => ["v3"]
  end # SCOPE GATE: leaving def

  local_variables # => ["v2"]
end # SCOPE GATE: leaving class
```

These entering and leaving points are called Scope Gates. Since you enter through Scope Gate via method definition you cannot access your `local_var` inside `hello` method.

---

You can use Scope Flattening concept the pass your variable through these gates.

For instance instead of using `def` for defining your method you can use `Module#define_method`.

```
local_var = "Hello"

define_method :hello do
  puts local_var
end
```

In the same way you can define your classes via `Class#New` so that your scope does not change when you pass through class definition.

```
local_var = 'test'

MyClass = Class.new do
  puts local_var #valid
end
```

instead of

```
class MyClass
  puts local_var #invalid
end
```

In the same way you should use `Module#New` if you want to pass your local variables through Module gates.

Example is taken from [Metaprogramming Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356476)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the function takes arguments and add the object as one of the arguments when you call it

```
local_var = "Hello"

def hello(some_local_var)
  puts local_var
end

hello(local_var)
```

Answer (score -9):

`local_var` is a local variable. Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in. (That's why they are *called* "local variables", after all!) So, obviously, since `local_var` is defined in the script scope, you cannot access it in the method scope.

Comment: If I am in a car and I have change in my pocket, then there is change in the car.  Plenty of other languages forward local variables to inner scopes, so there is no reason to treat Ruby's behavior as self evident.

Comment: @AdamTolley you're totally right but I'm guessing Ruby might be Jorg's first language and the scoping might seem obvious to him!

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel: Actually, it was about my fifteenth language, although by the time I wrote that answer, I was probably up another dozen or so. I don't really keep track.