# NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

New to Rails and had my app working just fine in production. However I recently updated the Heroku domain name and now I'm receiving the below error. I tried adding "config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false" as recommended in some similar searches but this is not doing the trick. Any ideas on what is causing this?

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
remote:        /tmp/build_a19bfb10c80282a277c9ba26e985613b/config/environments/production.rb:95:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_a19bfb10c80282a277c9ba26e985613b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_a19bfb10c80282a277c9ba26e985613b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to myapp.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/mysite.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git'
Aaron:myapp2$
```

Here are my .rb files:

**environment.rb**

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!



ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :port           => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT'],
  :address        => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER'],
  :user_name      => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN'],
  :password       => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'myapp.herokuapp.com',
  :authentication => :plain,
}

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

**application.rb**

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Myapp2
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.



  end
end
```

**development.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.seconds.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

**production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Attempt to read encrypted secrets from `config/secrets.yml.enc`.
  # Requires an encryption key in `ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]` or
  # `config/secrets.yml.key`.
  config.read_encrypted_secrets = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "myapp2_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :port           => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT'],
    :address        => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER'],
    :user_name      => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN'],
    :password       => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'myapp.herokuapp.com', #mydomain actually contains the realvalue
    :authentication => :plain,
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby local variable is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671259/ruby-local-variable-is-undefined)

Answer (score 4):

In your **production.rb**, these:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  # ...
}
```

should go inside the

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # ...
end
```

block, as `config` is only available there.

Comment: This helped me to resolve similar issue after migration to Rails 4.2 from 4.1 
Thank you